# Best locations in PUBG Mobile for birthday cake spawn

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

Any good locations where  there is high probability for birthday cake to spawn ? Like Villa is one in vekindi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the locations in every map in pubg where you can find the birthday cake to complete your achievement

Erangel:
1) Church in Yasnaya
2) Red building Outside Yasnaya near big prison building
3) Ban House outside pochinki

Vikendi:
1)Port
2)Villa
3)Castle
4)Dino Park

Sanhok:
1)Boot camp
2) cave
3) docks

Miramar:
1)El pozo
2)Puerto
3) Cobreria

Comment: I have completed the Achievement for Vikendi i would like to add main hall in abbey

Comment: mostly all churches in Erangel spawn this cake like the church in Pochinki and Ruins

Comment: I am not able to complete this achievement  dropped in  erangel,vikendi at different different locations but no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

I got 3 this week all in the Pochinki church.

Answer (score -2):

They spawn in those spots randomly but there were people that stated they had more luck either in the long houses beside Pochinki or in the church

https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBGMobile/comments/b4nc3q/tips_for_1100_title/